# Convertir Array de Objetos de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, object, programación-funcional, ecmascript-6

Necesitaría convertir un objeto devuelto de una llamada AJAX en otro objeto con diferentes propiedades.

El objeto en cuestión tiene una estructura similar a esta:

```
[
    {
        campo1: "algun valor",
        campo2: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
        campo3: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
        campo4: { Nombre: "Algun otro dato", Valor: 23456678 },
        campo5: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
        campo6: false
    },
    {
        campo1: "algun valor x",
        campo2: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
        campo3: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
        campo4: { Nombre: "Algun otro dato 2", Valor: 234566789 },
        campo5: { Id: 1234557, Nombre: "Algun otro datx" },
        campo6: true
    }, 
]
```

Y necesito que quede algo así:

```
{
    campo2: [
        { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" }
    ],
    campo3: [
        { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" }
    ],
    campo4: [
        { Nombre: "Algun otro dato", Valor: 23456678 },
        { Nombre: "Algun otro dato 2", Valor: 234566789 }
    campo5: [
        { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
        { Id: 1234557, Nombre: "Algun otro datx" }
    ]
}
```

He intentado utilizar algunas de las funciones de orden superior pero se nota que carezco de conocimiento, porque no logro dar en el clavo. En definitiva, intento crear el conjunto de un dropdown de forma que quede:

```
<select id="campo2">
    <option value="12345567">Algun otro dato</option>
</select>
<select id="campo3">
    <option value="12345567">Algun otro dato</option>
</select>
<select id="campo4">
    <option value="23456678">Algun otro dato</option>
    <option value="234566789">Algun otro dato 2</option>
</select>
<select id="campo5">
    <option value="12345567">Algun otro dato</option>
    <option value="1234557">Algun otro datx</option>
</select>
```

> **Nota**: Cabe destacar que no cuento con la información que viene de la llamada AJAX, o sea que no sé ni los valores que tiene, ni cuántos campos, ni qué campos. Básicamente son campos generados dinámicamente desde la base de datos.
>
> **Nota 2**: Si se fijan, los campos traídos en el segundo objeto están filtrados:
>
> - No están los valores que no son objetos.
> - No están los objetos repetidos.
> - No hay dos (o más) objetos padres.
>
> **Edición 1:** En respuesta a *@a-cedano*, el segundo JSON es generado de acuerdo a las anteriores conversiones, dadas las siguientes consideraciones:
>
> - Los nombres deben agruparse en un único objeto.
> - Se conservan sólo las propiedades cuyos valores son de tipo objeto.
> - Los valores deben agruparse en un mismo nombre quedando sólamente los valores únicos.

¿Cuál sería la mejor (o alguna) forma de encarar esto? Supongo que utilizando esas funciones de orden superior (bien).

Yo había intentado algo como lo siguiente (a modo de prueba), pero aún no me resultó:

```js
     let data = [
  {
   campo1: "algun valor",
   campo2: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
   campo3: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
   campo4: { Nombre: "Algun otro dato", Valor: 23456678 },
   campo5: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
   campo6: false
  },
  {
   campo1: "algun valor x",
   campo2: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
   campo3: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
   campo4: { Nombre: "Algun otro dato 2", Valor: 234566789 },
   campo5: { Id: 1234557, Nombre: "Algun otro datx" },
   campo6: true
  }, 
 ];

  const datos = [];
  data.forEach(d => {
    for(var prop in d) {
  if(typeof d[prop] === 'object') {
    let match = datos.find(x => Object.keys(x).indexOf('prop'));
   if(datos.length < 1 || match < 0)
   datos.push({ [prop]: d[prop] });
    else {
     if(datos[prop])
    datos[prop].push(d[prop]);
   }
  }
    }
  });
   console.log(datos)
```

Agradezco cualquier comentario constructivo.

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: lo agregué al post.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la lógica que se debe seguir? Debes explicar por qué motivo hay que ignorar el campo1 entero, por qué de los campos 2 y 3 se toman solo unos datos y de los campos 4 y 5 otros datos y si este sería siempre el mismo patrón de comportamiento, si siempre el objeto traerá 5 valores con la misma estructura, etc.

Comment: Lo agrego a la pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Una posible solución podría ser usando `reduce()` y `some()`

```js
const array = [{campo1: "algun valor",campo2: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },campo3: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },campo4: { Nombre: "Algun otro dato", Valor: 23456678 },campo5: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },campo6: false},{campo1: "algun valor x",campo2: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },campo3: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },campo4: { Nombre: "Algun otro dato 2", Valor: 234566789 },campo5: { Id: 1234557, Nombre: "Algun otro datx" },campo6: true}]

const resultado = array.reduce((p,c)=>{
    for(let prop in c){
        if(typeof c[prop] === 'object')
        if(prop in p){
            if(!p[prop].some(e=>JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify(c[prop]))) 
            p[prop].push(c[prop]);
        }else{
            p[prop] = [c[prop]];
        }
    }
    return p;
},{});

console.log(resultado);
```

Comparar los objetos `con JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify(c[prop]` no es lo ideal, si quieres algo ideal tendrías que iterar y comparar clave con clave y valor con valor.

Tal como @Rubén señala en los comentarios, voy describir lo mas brevemente posible porque `JSON.stringify(objetoA) === JSON.stringify(objetoB)` no es lo ideal.

Si comparamos estos dos objetos no hay duda de que son iguales:

```js
var foo = { a: 1, b:2 };
var bar = { a: 1, b:2  };

console.log(JSON.stringify(foo) === JSON.stringify(bar))
```

pero si cambiamos el orden:

```js
var foo = { a: 1, b:2 };
var bar = { b:2, a: 1  };

console.log(JSON.stringify(foo) === JSON.stringify(bar))
```

Da false, lo que ocurre es que historicamente los objetos de javascript no son obligatoriamente ordenados por la especificación del lenguaje. De manera que esos dos objetos son técnicamente iguales, pero no existe un método nativo para verificarlo. A partir de la especificación ES2015 las implementaciones del lenguaje deben mantener el orden de insersión, exepto si los key pueden ser parceados a enteros como "1", "5" etc. Entonces en este caso los dos objetos de arriba son distíntos.

Es decir: en teoría los navegadores deben mantener el orden de insersión, si creamos dos objetos con el mismo orden de insersión deberían poder ser comparables (siempre que no usemos "1", "3", "30" como key) porque el navegador mantendría el orden, en ese caso sería seguro usar JSON.stringify. 
Lo que ocurre es que algunos métodos de los navegadores hoy en día 07/19, cambian el orden de las propiedades de los objetos. Sería inútil que ponga acá los ejemplos porque cambia constantemente, el último que tenía noticia era sort() en chrome. Este cambio en el orden es a su vez tratado como bug en los navegadores por lo que se supone que en un futuro van a asegurar el orden.

Agregado a este problema, comparar dos objetos clave con clave y valor con valor es bastante complicado, porque podemos tener `n` niveles y esos niveles pueden ser otros objetos u arrays [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript).
Como conclusión, hoy lo ideal sería hacer un método específico para comparar dos objetos (clave con clave y valor con valor) siempre que conozcamos la estructura, sino sería mejor tratar de no usar objetos si necesitamos compararlos.

Comment: Tu pregunta sería mejor si explicaras brevemente porque no lo usado en tu respuesta no es lo ideal.

Comment: @Rubén si ya se, no lo explico porque es bastante largo, igualmente voy a intentar hacer un resumen.

Comment: Quizás con que menciones que funciona bien con propiedades que tienen como valor primitivo pero no cuando son objetos ya sería bastante mejor tu respuesta y todavía mejor si incluyes el enlace a una pregunta o referencia con la explicación amplia.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi versión.

```
const data = [
    {
        campo1: "algun valor",
        campo2: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
        campo3: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
        campo4: { Nombre: "Algun otro dato", Valor: 23456678 },
        campo5: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
        campo6: false
    },
    {
        campo1: "algun valor x",
        campo2: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
        campo3: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
        campo4: { Nombre: "Algun otro dato 2", Valor: 234566789 },
        campo5: true,
        campo6: { Id: 1234557, Nombre: "Algun otro datx" }
    },
];

const existingId = (obj1, obj2) => {
    return obj1.Id ? //Si obj1 tiene Id se compara Id, de lo contrario se compara Valor
        (obj1.Id === obj2.Id || obj1.Id === obj2.Valor) :
        (obj1.Valor === obj2.Id || obj1.Valor === obj2.Valor)
};

const resultObject = {};
data.forEach(lista => {
    Object.keys(lista).forEach(campoName => {//Se itera por cada llave del objeto
        if (lista[campoName] && lista[campoName].Nombre && (lista[campoName].Id || lista[campoName].Valor)) { //Se verifica que sea un objeto apto
            if (!resultObject[campoName]) { //Se verifica si el objeto ya tiene una llave con el mismo nombre
                resultObject[campoName] = []; //Se asigna si no existe
            }
            if (!resultObject[campoName].find(campo => existingId(campo, lista[campoName]))) { //Verificamos que el array de cada campo no contenga ya un Id o un Valor igual
                resultObject[campoName].push(lista[campoName])//Si no hay un Id o un Valor existente, agregamos al array
            }
        }
    });
});

console.log(resultObject);
```

Un ejemplo https://jsbin.com/detaxoqabo/edit?js,console

Basicamente primero filtro los objetos aptos, luego creo un elemento array en el objeto final si es que no existe un elemento con la misma llave. Finalmente agrego mi elemento al array objetivo, luego de verificar que ese array no tenga elementos con un Id o un Valor iguales al elemento que quiero agregar.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno espero que alguien publique algo similar pero mejor hecho, porque aunque cumple la necesidad éste código me parece lo contrario a "buenas prácticas" en JS:

```js
 let data =  [
   {
    campo1: "algun valor",
    campo2: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
    campo3: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
    campo4: { Nombre: "Algun otro dato", Valor: 23456678 },
    campo5: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
    campo6: false
   },
   {
    campo1: "algun valor x",
    campo2: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
    campo3: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
    campo4: { Nombre: "Algun otro dato 2", Valor: 234566789 },
    campo5: { Id: 1234557, Nombre: "Algun otro datx" },
    campo6: true
   }, 
  ];
 // Definimos nuevo objeto vacío
 const datos = {};
 // Iteramos el array de objetos existente
  data.forEach(dato => {
   // Iteramos las propiedades de cada objeto
  Object.keys(dato).forEach(prop =>  {
  // Si el valor de la propiedad iterada es de tipo objeto
  if(typeof dato[prop] === 'object') {
   // Si existe la propiedad en el objeto nuevo
   if(datos[prop]) {
     // Si la propiedad del objeto nuevo es un array
    if(Array.isArray(datos[prop])) {
    // Buscamos si existe un objeto con el ID del dato iterado en el array del nuevo objeto
    let match = datos[prop].find(datoProp => {
     if(datoProp.Id)
      return datoProp.Id === dato[prop].Id;
      else if(datoProp.Valor)
     return datoProp.Valor === dato[prop].Valor;
    });
    // Si no existe el objeto iterado en el nuevo objeto, lo añadimos al array del nuevo objeto
    if(!match)
     datos[prop].push(dato[prop]);
     }
   } else {
    // Añadimos la propiedad y su valor iterada al nuevo objeto
     let arr = []
     arr.push(dato[prop]);
    datos[prop] = arr;
   }
    }
  });
   });
    console.info(datos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Estuviste cerca, el problema que tenias es al comparar el objeto que estas iterando cambiando esa forma, (y el `if((typeof d[prop] === 'object' )` que lo ideal es el que no este que pase asi mejoras un poco mas de tiempo) tambien para compara todo el objeto o primitivos debes usar el método [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify);

A continuación el código

```js
let data = [{
  campo1: "algun valor",
  campo2: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
  campo3: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
  campo4: { Nombre: "Algun otro dato", Valor: 23456678 },
  campo5: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
  campo6: false
},{
  campo1: "algun valor x",
  campo2: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
  campo3: { Id: 12345567, Nombre: "Algun otro dato" },
  campo4: { Nombre: "Algun otro dato 2", Valor: 234566789 },
  campo5: { Id: 1234557, Nombre: "Algun otro datx" },
  campo6: true
}];
const datos = {};
data.forEach((d )=> {
  for(var prop in d) {
    if(!(typeof d[prop] === 'object')) continue;
    if(!datos[prop]){
     datos[prop] = [d[prop]]
    }else{
      if( !datos[prop].some(e=>JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify(d[prop]))){
      datos[prop].push(d[prop]);
      }
    } 

  }

});
   console.log(datos)
```